# No spacing below "Communities" when no other communities are present

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

When a user has no profile on another Stack Exchange site, apart from the one on which the profile is viewed, attached to their profile there appears to be no spacing between the header-line and the text "*This user does not participate in any other communities currently.*":

[image: Only one profile]

When a user has multiple profiles, e.g. like mine, the spacing is present:

[image]

Is this by design, or is a couple of pixels worth of spacing lacking?

---

I am on the latest Ubuntu Disco Dingo 19.04 and Firefox 68.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: Still an issue now. [The Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), for instance, has this problem.